# C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\dbghelp.h(1545): error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated

Tags: c, visual-studio, compiler-errors, warnings

When I build the renderdoc project from ["Playing for Data"](https://bitbucket.org/visinf/projects-2016-playing-for-data) paper I get the following errors (the author had no problem with VS13 so I wonder if it could be a VS15 problem):

```
1>------ Build started: Project: spirv, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
2>------ Build started: Project: crash_generation_client, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
3>------ Build started: Project: crash_generation_server, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
4>------ Build started: Project: exception_handler, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  PpTokens.cpp
4>  exception_handler.cc
3>  client_info.cc
3>  minidump_generator.cc
3>  crash_generation_server.cc
2>  crash_generation_client.cc
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\dbghelp.h(1545): error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\DbgHelp.h(1545): error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated (compiling source file client_info.cc)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\dbghelp.h(1545): warning C4091: 'typedef ': ignored on left of '' when no variable is declared
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\dbghelp.h(1545): error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated (compiling source file minidump_generator.cc)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\dbghelp.h(3191): warning C4091: 'typedef ': ignored on left of '' when no variable is declared
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\DbgHelp.h(1545): warning C4091: 'typedef ': ignored on left of '' when no variable is declared (compiling source file client_info.cc)
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\dbghelp.h(1545): warning C4091: 'typedef ': ignored on left of '' when no variable is declared (compiling source file minidump_generator.cc)
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\dbghelp.h(3191): warning C4091: 'typedef ': ignored on left of '' when no variable is declared (compiling source file minidump_generator.cc)
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\DbgHelp.h(3191): warning C4091: 'typedef ': ignored on left of '' when no variable is declared (compiling source file client_info.cc)
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\DbgHelp.h(1545): error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated (compiling source file crash_generation_server.cc)
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\DbgHelp.h(1545): warning C4091: 'typedef ': ignored on left of '' when no variable is declared (compiling source file crash_generation_server.cc)
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\DbgHelp.h(3191): warning C4091: 'typedef ': ignored on left of '' when no variable is declared (compiling source file crash_generation_server.cc)
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\DbgHelp.h(1545): error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\DbgHelp.h(1545): warning C4091: 'typedef ': ignored on left of '' when no variable is declared
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\DbgHelp.h(3191): warning C4091: 'typedef ': ignored on left of '' when no variable is declared
1>..\..\..\3rdparty\glslang\glslang\MachineIndependent\preprocessor\PpTokens.cpp(218): error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated
1>..\..\..\3rdparty\glslang\glslang\MachineIndependent\preprocessor\PpTokens.cpp(218): warning C4996: 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\string.h(119): note: see declaration of 'strcpy'
1>..\..\..\3rdparty\glslang\glslang\MachineIndependent\preprocessor\PpTokens.cpp(223): warning C4996: 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\string.h(119): note: see declaration of 'strcpy'
5>------ Build started: Project: renderdoc, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
5>  core.cpp
5>  win32_callstack.cpp
5>  replay_renderer.cpp
5>  serialiser.cpp
5>serialise\serialiser.cpp(493): error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated
5>serialise\serialiser.cpp(493): warning C4456: declaration of 'memoryBufEnd' hides previous local declaration
5>  serialise\serialiser.cpp(493): note: to simplify migration, consider the temporary use of /Wv:18 flag with the version of the compiler with which you used to build without warnings
5>  serialise\serialiser.cpp(446): note: see declaration of 'memoryBufEnd'
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\dbghelp.h(1545): error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated (compiling source file os\win32\win32_callstack.cpp)
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\dbghelp.h(1545): warning C4091: 'typedef ': ignored on left of '' when no variable is declared (compiling source file os\win32\win32_callstack.cpp)
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\dbghelp.h(3191): warning C4091: 'typedef ': ignored on left of '' when no variable is declared (compiling source file os\win32\win32_callstack.cpp)
5>core\core.cpp(854): error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated
5>core\core.cpp(854): warning C4456: declaration of 'it' hides previous local declaration
5>  core\core.cpp(854): note: to simplify migration, consider the temporary use of /Wv:18 flag with the version of the compiler with which you used to build without warnings
5>  core\core.cpp(839): note: see declaration of 'it'
5>replay\replay_renderer.cpp(49): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ImfOutputFile.h': No such file or directory
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 5 failed, 6 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Here's some screenshots I have:
[image]
[image]

I have Windows 10 Home Edition, and Visual Studio Enterprise 2015.
[image]

I then selected "Treat warnings as error" to "No" and still get errors:
[image]

```
1>------ Build started: Project: spirv, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
2>------ Build started: Project: crash_generation_client, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
3>------ Build started: Project: crash_generation_server, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
4>------ Build started: Project: exception_handler, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
2>  crash_generation_client.cc
4>  exception_handler.cc
3>  client_info.cc
3>  minidump_generator.cc
3>  crash_generation_server.cc
1>  PpTokens.cpp
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\DbgHelp.h(1545): error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated (compiling source file client_info.cc)
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\DbgHelp.h(1545): warning C4091: 'typedef ': ignored on left of '' when no variable is declared (compiling source file client_info.cc)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\dbghelp.h(1545): error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\dbghelp.h(1545): warning C4091: 'typedef ': ignored on left of '' when no variable is declared
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\dbghelp.h(3191): warning C4091: 'typedef ': ignored on left of '' when no variable is declared
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\DbgHelp.h(3191): warning C4091: 'typedef ': ignored on left of '' when no variable is declared (compiling source file client_info.cc)
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\dbghelp.h(1545): error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated (compiling source file minidump_generator.cc)
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\dbghelp.h(1545): warning C4091: 'typedef ': ignored on left of '' when no variable is declared (compiling source file minidump_generator.cc)
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\dbghelp.h(3191): warning C4091: 'typedef ': ignored on left of '' when no variable is declared (compiling source file minidump_generator.cc)
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\DbgHelp.h(1545): error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated (compiling source file crash_generation_server.cc)
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\DbgHelp.h(1545): warning C4091: 'typedef ': ignored on left of '' when no variable is declared (compiling source file crash_generation_server.cc)
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\DbgHelp.h(3191): warning C4091: 'typedef ': ignored on left of '' when no variable is declared (compiling source file crash_generation_server.cc)
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\DbgHelp.h(1545): error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\DbgHelp.h(1545): warning C4091: 'typedef ': ignored on left of '' when no variable is declared
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\DbgHelp.h(3191): warning C4091: 'typedef ': ignored on left of '' when no variable is declared
1>..\..\..\3rdparty\glslang\glslang\MachineIndependent\preprocessor\PpTokens.cpp(218): error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated
1>..\..\..\3rdparty\glslang\glslang\MachineIndependent\preprocessor\PpTokens.cpp(218): warning C4996: 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\string.h(119): note: see declaration of 'strcpy'
1>..\..\..\3rdparty\glslang\glslang\MachineIndependent\preprocessor\PpTokens.cpp(223): warning C4996: 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\string.h(119): note: see declaration of 'strcpy'
5>------ Build started: Project: renderdoc, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
5>  core.cpp
5>  win32_callstack.cpp
5>  replay_renderer.cpp
5>  serialiser.cpp
5>serialise\serialiser.cpp(493): error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated
5>serialise\serialiser.cpp(493): warning C4456: declaration of 'memoryBufEnd' hides previous local declaration
5>  serialise\serialiser.cpp(493): note: to simplify migration, consider the temporary use of /Wv:18 flag with the version of the compiler with which you used to build without warnings
5>  serialise\serialiser.cpp(446): note: see declaration of 'memoryBufEnd'
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\dbghelp.h(1545): error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated (compiling source file os\win32\win32_callstack.cpp)
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\dbghelp.h(1545): warning C4091: 'typedef ': ignored on left of '' when no variable is declared (compiling source file os\win32\win32_callstack.cpp)
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\dbghelp.h(3191): warning C4091: 'typedef ': ignored on left of '' when no variable is declared (compiling source file os\win32\win32_callstack.cpp)
5>replay\replay_renderer.cpp(49): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ImfOutputFile.h': No such file or directory
5>core\core.cpp(854): error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated
5>core\core.cpp(854): warning C4456: declaration of 'it' hides previous local declaration
5>  core\core.cpp(854): note: to simplify migration, consider the temporary use of /Wv:18 flag with the version of the compiler with which you used to build without warnings
5>  core\core.cpp(839): note: see declaration of 'it'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 5 failed, 6 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

The same about changing the warning level from 4 to 3:
[image]

Please suggest solutions.

Specifically I get error from this part of the code in `dbghelp.h`:

```
typedef enum {
    hdBase = 0, // root directory for dbghelp
    hdSym,      // where symbols are stored
    hdSrc,      // where source is stored
    hdMax       // end marker
};
```

and

```
   case PpAtomConstDouble:
        strcpy(ppToken->name, tokenText);
        ppToken->dval = atof(ppToken->name);
        break;
```

and

```
else if(header->version == SERIALISE_VERSION)
{
    const byte *memoryBufEnd = memoryBuf + length;

    memoryBuf += sizeof(FileHeader);
```

and

```
else
{
    auto it = m_WindowFrameCapturers.begin();
    // active window could be the first in our list, move
    // to second (we know from above there are at least 2)
    if(m_ActiveWindow == it->first)
        it++;
    m_ActiveWindow = it->first;
}



  Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
    Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: 'ImfOutputFile.h': No such file or directory  renderdoc   D:\playing-for-data\renderdoc\renderdoc\replay\replay_renderer.cpp  49  


  #include <ImfOutputFile.h>
```

UPDATE: I retargeted the solution to 10.0.14393.0 (which was by default selected), cleaned and built and got the same errors:
[image]

Comment: i think you need to lift down  warning level and you coud stay cool

Comment: like exactly at which level?

Comment: it's finished up i see.so find this file h.and try release conf

Comment: try to change confguration to release.i bet it would not help but some chances are there.then google about solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Visual Studio solution contains 13 C++ projects, and all of these probably have the "Treat warnings as errors" setting activated. Try disabling this options for all projects and compiling again.

Answer (score 2):

The issue with dbghelp.h is a true warning for a coding error.  The typedef designation requires a variable.  I believe you may want to update your library from Microsoft.